# Question with Netmiko and TextFSM against cisco IOSXE

Tags: python, cisco, netmiko, python-textfsm

Trying to do a check against Cisco IOSXE to see if any ports are still configured in the default VLAN.

```
Output = net_connect.send_command ('show int status', use_textfsm=true)
for i in output:
  if i["vlan"] == "1":
    print ('Not compliant')
  else:
    print ('Compliant')
```

This does work, but for a 48 port switch, I get 48 lines saying Compliant or Not Compliant. How can I change this so that if all ports are in a different vlan, lets say vlan 2, I get one line saying Complaint. And if ANY number of ports are in VLAN 1 , whether is be 1 port or 10 ports, I get one line saying "Not complaint", instead of 48 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options here. I will try to name some:

- Move for loop into a function

```py
def check_complaint(output):
  for i in output:
    if i["vlan"] == "1":
      return False
  return True

output = net_connect.send_command ('show int status', use_textfsm=true)
if check_complaint(output):
  print("Compliant")
else:
  print("Not Compliant")
```

Using the return statement in the functions allows the code to stop at the first interface in vlan 1

- Use a variable

```py
output = net_connect.send_command ('show int status', use_textfsm=true)
compliant = True
for i in output:
  if i["vlan"] == "1":
    compliant = False
    break

if compliant:
    print("Compliant")
else:
    print("Not Compliant")
```

Thanks to the `break` statment we will exit the for loop at the first vlan 1 match.

- Using `any` with a generator expression

```py
output = net_connect.send_command ('show int status', use_textfsm=true)
if any(i["vlan"] == "1" for i in output):
    print("Not Compliant")
else:
    print("Compliant")
```

The [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function will also stop at the first match of Vlan 1.

---

The code is not tested and not perfect but should give you some ideas how to solve your problem

Comment: Than you so much! The first example worked perfect. You guys are so helpful on here!